# php8 and Paypal IPN setup: Where does db INSERT upon successful handshake go?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Of the three files here- https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php
I have my Webhook URL set to the stock github version of- PaypalIPN.php  (this validates successfully 100% of the time, if I use example_usage.php... Doesn't work. If I use both as Webhooks... Doesn't work).

From the Paypal button side of things I'm able to post my website's active user (call him $MrUser) with this:

```
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                "custom_id":"<?php echo $MrUser; ?>",
                "description":"One hundred Webdollars",
                "amount":
                {
                    "currency_code":"USD",
                    "value":1.99
                    }
                }]
          });
        },
```

Here's the SQL I need to run upon successful validation (I change $MrUser to $kitty for clarity's sake):

```
require 'sqlconfig.php';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=UTF8";
try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}

$hashedIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$kitty = $_POST['custom']; // Not sure this is working yet, but this should give me $mrUser; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `Insert_upon_Paypal_success` (`date`,`hashedIP`,`username`,`webdollarAMT`) VALUES (now(),:hashedIP,:kitty,'100')";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':hashedIP', $hashedIP);
$statement->bindValue(':kitty', $kitty);
$inserted = $statement->execute();
```

I'm popping this into the PaypalIPN.php file upon validation, but, it doesn't work. Here's how I have it in there:

```
        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true; 
            // i.e. putting all of the SQL above right here.
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

I'm guessing I need to put the SQL in a specific place that I'm missing, as per the layout of the PaypalIPN.php file... Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use IPN with current PayPal Checkout integrations. It is very old technology (20+ years) and should be deprecated soon.

Webhooks are a successor to IPN. However, even they are unnecessary for normal payment processing -- better used only if you need automated notifications of post-checkout exceptions such as refunds or disputes.

For normal PayPal payments, do not use either.

---

Instead, use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use the (recently deprecated) Checkout-PHP-SDK for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call with PHP's curl or similar. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)